# SQLJoin Results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

1. Select * from a join b on a.id=b.id and a.vol<5
2. Select * from a join b on a.id=b.id where a.vol<5

Do they produce the same results？

If they don't produce the same results, a has 1000 rows, b jas 100 rows, how many rows will each produce?

Comment: Yes for the fact that you limit them with the same where clause and they are both implicit inner joins.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, it does.
A "Join" implies an "Inner Join" so it doesn't matter if you have an "and" in the join or a "Where" after the join.

It would be different if it was an "outer Join" Specifying a "Where" with an outer joined table will turn the join into an "Inner Join" or simply "Join"

Hope that made sense

Comment: The where clause does matter, greatly. I'd remove that from your answer. Also if there are more join conditions, the and Boolean in a join would affect the results

Comment: I only answered in context of the question and not assuming any more conditions. Perhaps you could explain why it matters in the questions asked?

Comment: You stated that since the OP is using an inner join it doesn't matter if they have a WHERE clause or an AND in the join condition. This is incorrect. If the OP removes the where clause their results will be different. Also, if they added another join condition with AND it would potentially change the results

Answer (score 0):

For an `INNER JOIN`, like the simple query you have here, they are the same.

For an `OUTER JOIN`, they might not be the same.

For example, take these two queries:

```
select * from orders o left join orderlines ol on ol.order_id = o.id where o.id=12345
```

and

```
select * from orders o left join orderlines ol on ol.order_id = o.id and o.id=12345
```

The first query will give you data on order #12345 and it's lines, if any. The second query will give you data from *all* orders, but only order #12345 will have any item data.

This also illustrates how the two options have different semantic meanings. Even if they produce the same results, the two queries from your question have different semantic meanings, which might be important as an application grows over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you satisfied from answers but I want to mention about another side of this usage.

This two method generates the same result but compiler uses the different techniques to  get the result.

Of course, different technique generates different results. But when ? It is very hard to illustrate the stiation but I will try to explain.

Think that we have two table but first table has isDeleted column for records. This application does not deletes the rows and get just updates the IsDeleted column and ignored that records.

In first case if you do not filter records in ON operator and you filtered it in where criteria. These records will be included in other joins and you will calculate the result wrong. Think that you joined this table Amounts table. The result is wrong because deleted records included and then you filtered them in where criteria.

This difference can lead to very big mistakes specially in queries which has many joins.

I wish I succeded the explanation. I m not good at. :)